# How do I get tomcat 5.5 to run behind apache 2 with mod_rewrite passing through requests to mod_jk and stripping app context?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite, mod-jk

Ok, so I want to get a webapp running in tomcat (5.5) to run behind apache 2 (2.2.3 to be precise) serving from the root of the site (i.e. without the context), with static content being served via apache.

So if the app is running under "`/myapp`" on tomcat I want to use apache (plus `mod_rewrite`) to make it behave as if it's running under "`/`" instead.

`Mod_jk` is setup and working ok.  I can access the app from "`/myapp`", but I can't quite get the last bit working.  Below is the config I've got for `mod_rewrite` to try and get this working.  It correctly gets rewrites `/static/` urls to get apache to serve them from the unpacked webapp and if I enable the rewrite log I see that it does attempt to pass through all other requests to `/myapp` via `mod_jk`.  However it seems that mod_jk is not processing the request afterwards.

```
JkMount /myapp/*      worker1

RewriteEngine On

# ensure static stuff gets served by apache
RewriteRule ^/static/(.*)$ /var/lib/tomcat5.5/webapps/myapp/static/$1 [L]
# everything else should go through tomcat
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /myapp/$1 [L,PT]
```

When I've done this with apache 1 in the past I've had to make sure `mod_jk` get's loaded before `mod_rewrite`, but I can't seem to achieve this under apache 2.  Any thoughts?  How do other people usually do this?

Comment: Apache 2.2 (I'll update the question to mention this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get this working in the end.  It appears that I need to set a JkOption to:

```
JkOptions     +ForwardURICompat
```

And then `mod_jk` looks at the rewritten URL.  Must admit not 100% sure quite why this works, but I believe it's reverting to an older form of behaviour.  If anyone can tell me a better/more correct way of doing this I'd love to know.

Answer (score 1):

May be better use Apache for proxy instead of mod_jk.
Something like this:

ProxyPass  /static/  http://localhost:8080/myapp/static/

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier or more transparent what happens if you use either Tomcat Virtual Hosts or different connectors for different hosts and just deploy root applications (at "/") and setup Apache mod_jk forwarding to the different connectors or virtual hosts.

Note: When I needed this I've worked with different connectors for different tomcat hosts or Engines (can't remember) and deployed ROOT applications. I've never tried virtual hosts (name based) in tomcat, only guessing that this could work.

Benefit: no path translation, thus a lot easier to understand once you have to make changes to the installation months after initial deployment.

I confess, it feels somewhat strange, but the benefit of readability is worth a lot to me.

Answer (score -1):

We use the 'R' flag instead of 'PT':

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /myapp/$1 [L,R]
```

**Edit:**
I missed the point to not alter the URL the user sees. An alternative way is to do:

```
JkMount /* worker1
JkUnmount /static/* worker1
```

Then you won´t need the RewriteRule's.

And according to [Apache Tomcat Site](http://tomcat.apache.org/security-jk.html) the new default settings of the `mod_jk` are incompatible with `mod_rewrite` and you should use `+ForwardURICompatUnparsed`.

Comment: That will just do a redirect though, so the final URL (that the user sees) with have /myapp at tge beginning.  Basically I'm trying to get http://mysite.com/ to work, rather than having to redirect the user to http://mysite.com/myapp/ (which is a bit ugly).